# Two New Column SQL Server: one with journalist Id, one with count of journalist per row

Tags: sql-server, string-aggregation

I am trying to slice out, a column in my SQL server database where the table is about articles written by journalists. The issue is that there is no Id for each journalist but there is the "Writer" column, where the name of the journalist is placed, and if he/she wrote in pairs, the name follows one after the other.

What I want to achieve is to:

1) Each journalist be assigned its own row and Id **(which I would call it "WriterId")**

2) A second row that counts the number of journalists in that sequence.

How to replicate:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
ArticleId   int,
Title   varchar(50),
Writer  varchar(50),
Body    varchar(max)
);
```

and insert the values:

```
INSERT INTO article (ArticleId, Title, Writer, Body)
VALUES 
(1, 'Title Article 1', 'Sabao Fulano, Sapato Feio, Jose Perreira', 'Body of Article 1'), 
(2, 'Title Article 2', 'Feijao Mauricio', 'Body of Article 2'), 
(3, 'Title Article 3', 'Toze Jose', 'Body of Article 3');
```

Desirable output:

```
ArticleId   Title             Writer        WriterId Count(Writer)    Body
    1       Title Article 1   Sabao Fulano        W1     3            Body of Article 1
    1       Title Article 1   Sapato Feio         W2     3            Body of Article 1
    1       Title Article 1   Jose Perreira       W3     3            Body of Article 1
    2       Title Article 2   Feijao Mauricio     W4     1            Body of Article 2
    3       Title Article 3   Toze Jose           W5     1            Body of Article 3
```

Any clue how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this really SQL Server? SQL Server doesn't use backticks (`\``) for object quotes, it uses brackets (`[]`). If you really are using SQL Server, don't use the `text` datatype, use `varchar(MAX)`. The datatype has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005/2008 (I can't remember which exactly). If you are using MySQL (which i suspect you are) then update your tags please.

Comment: `there is no Id for each journalist` - So, what is that `WriterId` column doing in the results, and how did it magically get filled?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have editted to reflect sql server. I am using SQL Server 2017 @TimBiegeleisen. The Id for each journalist is to be defined manually after splitting from the comma separated names Peter B.

Comment: To start with, **you really need a `Writer` table**. Don't put redundant and possibly repetitive Writer data into the `Article` table - think of what happens if you do that and then find out you to need to store their Birthdate, Gender, ...?

Comment: I hope none of the writers have a comma in their name. :)

Comment: @PeterB that's a good point. The database guys at my company are working to improve the system. There should be indeed a writer table. As of now as I am not really a database guy, I just need quick insights for the editorial team at my company. @ Larnu I hope so too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2017, there is a convenient solution using [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT
    ArticleId,
    Title,
    Body,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ArticleId) writer_count
    VALUE AS Writer
FROM article  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Writer, ',');
```

[image]

### Demo

The only comment I would add about `STRING_SPLIT` here is that the column which receives the split values has to be called `value`.  But, we can then alias that column away to another name, e.g. `Writer`, if we want to do that.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question! The demo is amazing too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Substring and split a value function To Get The Same Result

```
SELECT a.Articleid, A.Title,  
 Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Writer,a.Body,count(*) over (partition 
  by articleid) Writer_count    
   FROM  (SELECT articleid,body,Title,  
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Writer, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Writer 
       FROM  #article) AS A CROSS APPLY writer.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I have hard time to understand what's happening in your query. Can you try to make a sqlfiddle demo or explain? Thanks.

Comment: In this the sub query splits the values separated by commas **With the Help of XML** in writer column and stored each values as a row by creating table 'split' with column 'a'.Then the main retrives the values from subquery and join with other specified columns.